# filteredfruitData.map is not a function - react error

Tags: reactjs

I have below fruitData

```
const fruitData = [{ fruitname: 'apple', fruitprice: '200', fruitcolor: 'red'},
{ fruitname: 'mango', fruitprice: '500', fruitcolor: 'yellow'},
{ fruitname: 'berry', fruitprice: '300', fruitcolor: 'red'}];
```

In below return section, I am trying to check which fruits in fruitData have color ‘red’.

```
return (
<section>
  {fruitData.map((info) => {
    if (info.fruitcolor === ‘red’) {
 // return filtered fruit data
      return null;
    }
```

Can you help me how I should return filtered fruit data. I want it to be in below format

```
 const filteredfruitData = [{ fruitname: 'apple', fruitprice: '200', fruitcolor: 'red'},

{ fruitname: 'berry', fruitprice: '300', fruitcolor: 'red'}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `filter` method in this scenario,

```
  return (
    <section>
      {fruitData
        .filter((fruit) => fruit.fruitcolor === "red")
        .map((info) => (
          <span>{info.fruitname} </span>
        ))}
    </section>
  );
```

[Check demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-burnell-61pk0b?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` method to filter on `red` color

```js
const filteredData = fruitData.filter((fruit) => fruit.fruitcolor === "red")
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
function App() {
const fruitData = [{ fruitname: 'apple', fruitprice: '200’, fruitcolor: ‘red’},
{ fruitname: 'mango', fruitprice: '500’, fruitcolor: ‘yellow’},
{ fruitname: ’berry', fruitprice: ‘300’, fruitcolor: ‘red’}]

const filteredFruits = fruitData.filter((item) => item.fruitcolor === "red")

return (
<section>
  {filteredFruits.map((fruit) => {
   // Your code
   })}
</section>
)
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try this using array method map to copy your data and showing the result.

```
const fruitData = [
    { fruitname: "apple", fruitprice: "200", fruitcolor: "red"},
    { fruitname: 'mango', fruitprice: '500', fruitcolor: 'yellow'},
    { fruitname: 'berry', fruitprice: '300', fruitcolor: 'red'},
];
return (
 <section>
   {fruitData.map((data) => {
     if (data.fruitcolor === "red") return data;
   })}
</section>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid using adding any escaping logic while using `Array.map()` method. Instead, you may use `Array.filter()` method before `Array.map()`.

```js
const fruitData = [{
    fruitname: "apple",
    fruitprice: "200",
    fruitcolor: "red"
  },
  {
    fruitname: "mango",
    fruitprice: "500",
    fruitcolor: "yellow"
  },
  {
    fruitname: "berry",
    fruitprice: "300",
    fruitcolor: "red"
  },
];

const filteredFruitData = fruitData.filter(
  ({
    fruitcolor
  }) => fruitcolor === "red"
);

console.log("filteredFruitData", filteredFruitData);
```